# qv2ray failed to work on mac os mojave 10.15.5 with v2ray can not executable

Tags: mac

### environment

mac os catalina 10.15.5(19F101)

v2ray version v4.24.2 https://github.com/v2ray/v2ray-core/releases/download/v4.24.2/v2ray-macos.zip

qv2ray version v2.5.0 https://github.com/Qv2ray/Qv2ray/releases/download/v2.5.0/Qv2ray-v2.5.0.macOS-x64.dmg

### problem

when i download both files and install Qv2ray and unzip v2ray-macos then push all files in the v2ray-macos to the target folder in `/Users/you_user_name/Library/Preferences/qv2ray/vcore`, and press the `Check V2ray Core Settings` if faile with message `V2ray core failed with an exit code: 255`

Comment: when i searched the error msg `V2ray core failed with an exit` in the source code in `https://github.com/Qv2ray/Qv2ray`, i foud  it's here `https://github.com/Qv2ray/Qv2ray/blob/737545329dd59757038413831e5fed883470fe49/src/core/kernel/V2rayKernelInteractions.cpp#L110` what fails.

Comment: i dive into the depressed folder and execute `./v2ray` it failed with operation not permitted, then i execute `sudo chmod +x v2ray; sudo ./v2ray` it still failed with operation not permitted.